# Moving CSS Header Logo Closer to Edge of Layout

Tags: asp.net, css

I'm helping a friend fix a few small things on his website and I have a few questions about a CSS issue I'm having. Now before everyone tells me to read a CSS book before I try to move this logo closer to the edge of the screen - understand I'm an Android/Java developer (primarily) and I'm pretty sure I can handle this simple task.

It's just acting a bit funny and I need a quick hand...

I have our header logo: `img src="img/logo.png`

which is appearing a bit too far from the left edge.

I've taken a look at the image it's self and it's cropped appropriately.

How might we move this logo a bit to the left? (Every time I attempt to change the #header-inner value the entire header collapses for some strange reason.)

### Screenshot:

[image]

### CSS Source:

```
/*====HEADER
=======================================================*/

#header {   
    border-top: 1px solid #525252;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #525252;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #1e1e1e;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #1e1e1e;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #1e1e1e; 
    margin-bottom: 42px;
}

#header-inner {
    width: 930px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(../img/back-light-1.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding: 20px 0;    
}

#title {
    float: left;
}

#logo h1 {
    font-family: Bebas, Arial, sans-serif;  
    color: #f7f7f7;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #262626;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#logo h1 a {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#logo h1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

#logo p {   
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}

#logo img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*====NAVIGATION
=======================================================*/

#navigation {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1200;
}

#navigation li {
    display: block; 
    float: left;    
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;  
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear;
}

#navigation li:hover {
    background-color: #121212;
    text-shadow: none;
}

#navigation li a {
    font-family: Bebas, Arial, sans-serif;  
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;  
    margin-bottom: 0px;         
}

#navigation li a span {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 9px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
}

#navigation li .active-nav, #navigation li .active-nav:hover {
    background-color: #8eaf2a;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #333;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px; 
}

#navigation li.dropdown {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

#navigation li.dropdown .active-nav {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

### HTML Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Company Name - NY</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<!--imports the main css file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
<!--imports prettyPhoto css file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" />

<!--imports jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<!--imports twitter feed plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<!--imports easing plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
<!--imports prettyPhoto plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<!--imports jQuery Tools plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<!--imports jQuery superfish plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<!--imports jQuery jflickrfeed plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
<!--imports jQuery AsyncSlider plugin-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.asyncslider.min.js"></script>

<!--imports custom javascript code-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {  
    // Setup Slider
    $("#async-slider").asyncSlider({
        keyboardNavigate: true,
        easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
        minTime: 600,
        maxTime: 1500,
        autoswitch: 4800,
        centerPrevNextNav: false,
        slidesNav: false
    });
});
</script>
<!--[if IE 7]><link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>      
    <div id="header" class="pattern-1">
        <div id="header-inner">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="image description"/>   
                <div id="title">
                    <h1><a href="index.asp">Company Name - NY</a></h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div><!-- end title -->
            </div><!-- end logo -->

            <ul id="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a class="active-nav" href="index.asp">Home

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.asp">About Us

                    </a>
                </li>               <li>
                    <a href="#">Energy Partnership Program

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Products

                    </a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact Us

                    </a></li>




                                <li>
                    <a href="#">Affiliates

                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- end navigation -->

            <div class="clear"></div><!-- end clearfix -->
        </div><!-- end header-inner -->
    </div><!-- end header -->

<!-- BEGIN ASYNC SLIDER -->

    <div id="content-slider">       
        <ul id="async-slider">
            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left" style="width: 425px; height: 242px">
                    <h2>Company Name - NY</h2>
                    <h3><i>"A not just for profit company!"</i></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/sliders/async/1.png" alt="image" width="468" height="329" />      

            </li>

            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>Energy Efficient Lighting Products to fit your needs</h2>
                    <h3><i>T8, T12, E27, Outdoor Lighting, etc</i></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/sliders/async/2Transparent.png" alt="image" width="347" height="305" /> 

            </li>

            <li class="slide">
                <div class="three-fifth fl-left">
                    <h2>Tax Credits and Grants available for those who qualify</h2>
                    <h3><i>Federal, State and Local tax incentives available</i></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

                <img class="fl-right" src="img/sliders/async/3.gif" alt="image" />   

            </li>

            <li class="slide">          

                <img class="fl-left" src="img/sliders/async/4Transparent.png" alt="image" width="347" height="305" />

                <div class="three-fifth last fl-right">
                    <h2>Create a Comprehensive Energy Profile</h2>
                    <h3><i>Calculate your Energy Savings in Real Time!</i></h3>
                    <p>...</a>
                </div>  

            </li>

        </ul>   
        <div class="clear"></div><!-- end clearfix -->          
    </div><!-- end content-slider -->       

<!-- END ASYNC SLIDER -->

    <div class="container pattern-1">
        <div class="tagline">
            <div class="tagline-text">
                <h2>Welcome to Company Name - NY</span>  </h2>
                <p><i>"A not just for profit Company!"</i></p>
            </div><!-- end tagline-text -->

            <div class="tagline-btn">
                <a href="#"><span class="main">"Calculate your Energy Savings NOW!"</span><span class="arrow-btn"></span></a>
            </div><!-- end tagline-btn -->
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div><!-- end tagline -->  
    </div><!-- end container -->

    <div id="wrapper">  

        <div class="one-half">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h3>EP Program</h3>
                <span class="box-subtitle">Energy Partnership</span>
            </div><!-- end box-title -->    
            <p>Today, with the emphasis on greener energy, products and way of 

Life….....The economic climate has businesses looking for any type of

Edge they can utilize to maximize the earnings potential of every dollar

Earned. This requires a proactive, well concieved, structured and

Customized new approach to rectify some of the same issues that have 

Plagued all companies regardless of size or industry.

How would you like to be able to cut spending?? Lower monthly 

Expenses?? Increase productivity (thus creating growth in revenue and

Potential earnings)?? While not sacrificing employees or the level of

Quality of the products or services offered.Even generate

Revenue from an expense, while improving your workplace environment.

Our epp or energy partnership program takes all fctors of your day-
To-day operations into considertaton when we examine your current 

Energy consumption patterns. ....We analyze the data collected, then 

Focus on your specific (customized) needs. At this point we strategize 

Multiple options that can all be used to save you 40-75% on your very 

Next electric bill.

We offer several different ways within the “ep program” to help 

Implement your customized plan designed for you to attain these lofty

Goals.</p>
            <a class="button" href="about.asp">Continue reading</a>
        </div><!-- end one-half -->

        <div class="one-half last services">
            <div class="box-title">
                <h3>Services</h3>
                <span class="box-subtitle">Company Name - NY</span>
            </div><!-- end box-title -->    
            <div class="one-fourth">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>Energy Resources:</h4>
                    <img src="img/icons/spanner.png" alt="image" />                     
                </div><!-- end box-title -->    
                <p>Information and resources about energy and energy savings.</p>
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth last">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>Educational Resources:</h4>
                    <img src="img/icons/pencil.png" alt="image" />                      
                </div><!-- end box-title -->    
                <p>Your one-stop source for energy efficiency knowledge.</p>
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->       

            <div class="one-fourth">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>Create Your Energy Profile:</h4>
                    <img src="img/icons/gear.png" alt="image" />                        
                </div><!-- end box-title -->    
                <p>Create and Analyze your comprehensive energy profile for FREE!</p>
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth last">
                <div class="box-title">
                    <h4>Tax Counseling:</h4>
                    <img src="img/icons/phone.png" alt="image" />                       
                </div><!-- end box-title -->    
                <p>Find out what Federal, State and Local tax breaks you may qualify for.</p>
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->       

        </div><!-- end one-half -->     

        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="separator"></div>       

        <div class="title-col">
            <h2>Our Latest Projects</h2>
            <p>"Coming Soon"</p>
            <a class="button" href="#">View Portfolio </a>
        </div><!-- end main-col -->

        <div class="gallery-thumbs-caption">
            <div class="one-fourth">
                <div class="gallery-overlay">   
                    <a class="zoom" href="img/portfolio/large/001.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto">
                        <img class="box-img" src="img/box-img-1.jpg" alt="description" width="200" height="122" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="img-caption">
                    <h4>Project Title One</h4>                  
                    <p>Fusce scelerisque pellentue mi. Suspen disse elementellus lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div><!-- end img-caption -->
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth">
                <div class="gallery-overlay">   
                    <a class="play" href="http://vimeo.com/7449107" rel="prettyPhoto">
                        <img class="box-img" src="img/box-img-2.jpg" alt="description" width="200" height="122" />
                    </a>                    
                </div>                          

                <div class="img-caption">
                    <h4>Project Title Two</h4>                  
                    <p>Fusce scelerisque pellentue mi. Suspen disse elementellus lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div><!-- end img-caption -->
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth last">
                <div class="gallery-overlay">   
                    <a class="link" href="http://www.themeforest.net?iframe=true&width=70%&height=60%" title="themeforest.net" rel="prettyPhoto">
                        <img class="box-img" src="img/box-img-3.jpg" alt="description" width="200" height="122" />
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="img-caption">
                    <h4>Project Title Three</h4>                    
                    <p>Fusce scelerisque pellentue mi. Suspen disse elementellus lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div><!-- end img-caption -->
            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- end gallery-thumbs-caption -->   

        <div class="separator"></div>   

        <div class="title-col">
            <h2>Latest News</h2>
            <p>"Coming Soon"</p>
            <a class="button" href="#">Continue Reading </a>
        </div><!-- end main-col -->

        <div class="news">
            <div class="one-fourth">                
                <h4>Comunion And Two Oracles</h4>
                <span class="news-meta">by John Doe on Mar 22, 2012</span>  

                <p>Praesent lobortis, turpis sit amet dignissim sagittis. Fusce scelerisque pellentesque mi... <a href="#">read more</a></p>    

            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth">
                <h4>Orion The Hunter</h4>
                <span class="news-meta">by John Doe on Mar 22, 2012</span>  

                <p>Praesent lobortis, turpis sit amet dignissim sagittis. Fusce scelerisque pellentesque mi... <a href="#">read more</a></p>    

            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="one-fourth last">
                <h4>Through The Looking Glass</h4>
                <span class="news-meta">by John Doe on Mar 22, 2012</span>  

                <p>Praesent lobortis, turpis sit amet dignissim sagittis. Fusce scelerisque pellentesque mi... <a href="#">read more</a></p>    

            </div><!-- end one-fourth -->

            <div class="clear"></div>

        </div><!-- end news -->     

    </div><!-- end wrapper -->


<!--#include file="footer.asp" -->
```

Comment: Can we see the CSS you've got just for the `#logo`?

Comment: copying the entire page of HTML doesn't help us (in fact, it keeps many from even trying). provide the `#logo` specific HTML and CSS.

Comment: Ok - give me two minutes and I'll put it up : )

Comment: Do you have a link to the site showing this problem?  I can't reproduce it with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

This depends if a padding value is set on #header-inner, you reduce the left padding value to move #logo closer to the left.

if you want to move only the logo to the left without changing the padding. You can use negative left margin or left value. This would require to add position: relative to the #logo element ( in case of using left) or when using negative left margin (it does not need to be set to relative positioning).

Comment: Strange... I just reduced my padding value from 20 to 5 and it still didn't move it to the left. 


I have the following: 

#header-inner {
 width: 930px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: url(../img/back-light-1.png) no-repeat left center;
 padding: 20px 0; 
}

Comment: Your left padding is 0. padding: 20px 0 only concerns top and bottom values which are both 20px. What are the #logo styles?

Comment: Look in your css for #logo if any styles. Or inspect the element in Chrome F12 - inspect element. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnWL2d9bGPk

Comment: The only references to #logo are the ones shown above

Comment: and I used inspect element on that space and it's referring to the line #header-inner {
 width: 930px;


and when I try to drop that value down to like 250 tho whole header shrinks into this tiny little mess... (which needless to say is undesirable) : )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HCLdW/8/ Just do this: 
    #logo img {
    /* ADD STYLES TO MOVE LOGO LEFT */
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
}

Comment: I tried what you said verbatim and it caused the logo to move to the right for some reason (thrown haphazardly seeming underneath some other text - I send a screenshot if you need it) 

and it looks the same if I do this:


 #logo img {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative; left: -15px;
}

Comment: Here's my entire working as is CSS if you'd like to take a look: 

http://pastebin.com/HhhHWDkN

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49433/discussion-between-sigma-and-user3063132)

Comment: Why did you offer to continue in chat then once we got there said you couldn't offer any help? That was, um... strange :)

Comment: You got my help  and I gave an answer on how to move the logo around without affecting the surrounding elements, didn't I? But I cannot start debugging all the page you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, You've got the `float:left` set on `#logo img` so any `padding` of the parent element won't take effect unless they are `relative`ly aligned with those elements nearby (`#logo *` and `header*`). From what I can tell in your code the only other DOM aligned left is the `title`.

When using relative layout,this offsetting can be accomplished via either:

- `Padding` in the parent group, in your case `#header-inner` and `#logo`
- `Margin`s of the specific element in your case `#logo img`

Going by your current hierarchy you parent to children and siblings: 
`header` -> `header-inner` -> `logo` -> `img | title | h1 | p`

The higher (closest to the left) the level of the relationship, will have a direct effect on any related children or siblings.

if you're going to use `float`ing with a grouped set I would recommend using `float` in the parent `div` and inherit that from the child like:

```
#header {
    float:left; 

#header-inner{ /*direct parent of #logo*/
  float:inherit;
}


#logo{  /*direct parent of #logo img*/
  float:inherit;
  ...
}

#logo h1 {
  float:inherit;
  ...
}

#logo p{
  float:inherit;
  ...
}

#logo img{
  float:inherit;
  ...
}
```

That at least should ensure the parent is contributing to the relative position. You may also want to consider the `clear:left|right|both` which ensures your layouts skip content based on your choice.

It may be worth noting that some grouped elements when using `float` it may be helpful to specify `width` of each in the group.

I'm relatively new to CSS myself but I've encountered alignment woes when using `float` that aren't always immediately obvious in a nested layout.

Comment: I tried your answer and appear to have screwed everything up a bit... 

I included my entire CSS here (since we seem to have some sort of nesting issue - mind taking a peek?) 

http://pastebin.com/p9vEuiy3

Comment: When using `float` it's highly likely to cause a knock on effect in the alignment of the entire page. If you're mixing fixed elements with relative ones the "floating" ones will be layered over the top. 

my general rule of thumb is:
header 
`float:left`
nav: 
`float:left|right`
content
`float:left`
aside
`float:right`
footer
`float:left`

looking over your pastebin it's in relation to the footer which doesn't appear directly related to this issue? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ This is a nice explanation of the concepts.

Comment: I've revised some information in my post to clarify my meaning, apologies as I say I'm a newbie to CSS myself.